# Running multiple apps as Admin

Tags: c#, security, uac, admin, runas

I've need to add a function to my C# WPF application to fix up certain registry entries.
This would be done by calling `regsvr32.exe /s mylib.dll`. Now, this should be easy to do from what I see using the `runas` verb with a new `Process` object. (My dll does require admin rights due to some registry keys it writes to.)

But the problem is there are multiple DLLs, thus multiple invocations of `regsvr32.exe`, and it is not possible to put all the registrations into a single `.dll`. But were I to just `runas` multiple times, the user would get as many UAC dialogs as I start it... and I don't want that.

I want just a single dialog, and I really really want to avoid having a mystery extra `fixer.exe` file to have to do the launching instead. Now, I only know Windows Security stuff on a really basic level, but shouldn't it be possible to get an 'admin' token somehow (which gets me the UAC dialog) and use that to launch the different processes?

Comment: I usually have a cmd prompt runas administrator.  So, whenever I need admin privilege, I just run commands there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use command line arguments, and shell to your own .exe running that process as an admin.  When your application loads, check for those command line arguments...If they are there, register all of your dlls, then exit.

Or, you could write a batch file that registers all of the dlls, and shell to that with admin rights.

Comment: I guess that's an option. Does it make a difference for the kind of UAC dialog the user sees?

Comment: I ended up going for this solution. Maybe not the prettiest, but it is self-contained and the simplest compared to the other answer which are (in my eyes) overengineered for my purpose. Thank you for connecting the dots which, in hindsight, are pretty obvious. :)

Comment: The 2nd option mentioned (via batch) is described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843750/1016343)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is security.  You have three options:

1. Create a service account and run the application with service account privileges.
2. Prep the target machines that the application will run on with some sort of install package.
3. Use powershell to invoke regsvr32.exe with admin rights ->

> ```
> function Run-Elevated ($scriptblock)
> {
>   # TODO: make -NoExit a parameter
>   # TODO: just open PS (no -Command parameter) if $sb -eq ''
>   $sh = new-object -com 'Shell.Application'
>   $sh.ShellExecute('powershell', "-NoExit -Command $sb", '', 'runas')
> }
> ```

I would opt for option 2, as registering dll's are more than an installation step.  The registering of the dll crosses the boundary of the account privileges needed to run the main application.  If your app is running on a domain environment an MSI could be rolled out to prep each machine?

Comment: I don't want to use .msi packages. I've tried it in the past with a similar situation: native shell extensions just don't play nice with it. You need to do stuff with merge modules, different install packages, .msi's running other bit-specific .msi files that it isn't worth the effort for a relatively small tool that I am not getting paid for. Inbetween shims, registry redirection, and wanting 32-bit OS to only have the 32-bit shell extension, whereas 64-bit gets 32-bit AND 64-bit varieties installed, it is hell. Making my binaries do the registrations circumvents pretty much all those issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one single UAC prompt, there is already an answer at Stackoverflow, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1016343).

This script elevates itself once, and you can execute a sequence of commands which all need elevated rights, so you don't get multiple UAC prompts anymore.

In your case, this means you can just append the invokations of

```
regsvr32.exe /s mylib1.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mylib2.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mylib3.dll
```

at the end of the script mentioned above, i.e.

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .

REM The following code will cause Windows UAC to prompt only once 

regsvr32.exe /s mylib1.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mylib2.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mylib3.dll
```

and the UAC dialog will only appear once.